# npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 не собирается проект

Tags: java, maven

Полный код ошибки

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
[ERROR] npm ERR! argv "D:\\projects\\myproject\\pgu\\node\\node.exe" "D:\\projects\\myproject\\pgu\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--false"
[ERROR] npm ERR! node v0.12.7
[ERROR] npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
[ERROR] npm ERR! code E404
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! 404 Not found : @sitex/smev-pgu2
[ERROR] npm ERR! 404 
[ERROR] npm ERR! 404  '@sitex/smev-pgu2' is not in the npm registry.
[ERROR] npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
[ERROR] npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of '@sitex/chesmev-pgu'
[ERROR] npm ERR! 404 
[ERROR] npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
[ERROR] npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     D:\projects\myproject\pgu\npm-debug.log
```

стоит node. прописал инструкции
npm init, npm init --yes
нормально отработало

но после npm install

```
npm WARN chesmev@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN chesmev@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

затем нажимаю package и ошибка в финале.

Comment: WARN не представляет опасности, а сам package.json у вас содержит `@sitex/smev-pgu2`?

Comment: А, стоп, ошибка же в том, что npm не может найти его в репозитории

Comment: не может найти файл package.json?

Comment: Нет, зависимость `@sitex/smev-pgu2`, которая указана в `@sitex/chesmev-pgu`

Comment: Спасибо решило проблему!